# window.onload inconsistent cross-browser?

Tags: javascript, safari, microsoft-edge, onload

Does window.onload not work consistently with some browsers..?

I've put a script together purposely utilizing native JavaScript (no library or framework used). I know there may be some issues with cross-browser compatibility. However, there is something different occurring with the Edge browser at least.

The entire page works as expected in webkit(Chrome, not yet in Safari), and it seems to work perfect in the latest Firefox as well.

In Microsoft's Edge browser it seems to have a starter issue, or, it's not booting well every time on the onload trigger. It works perfectly sometimes, if I refresh the page enough.

What can possibly explain this? Edge may be better in this case as I'm not sure if it's working in Safari at all.

[Codepen link!](https://codepen.io/kjerrya/project/editor/XbNJpE)

```
 window.onload = function() {
// if you're savvy enough for it... please check codepen for the full code
    /* automation from input */
wght_input.oninput = function() {
    x = this.value;
    var bodyweight = x;

    // when puts into form input
    this.onchange = function() {
        frmFeed[0].innerHTML = "";
        recc_wght();
        getadd();
        whatsTotal();
        resetButton.click() ;
    };

var kgs = curr_wght_set_amt * kg; //convert lbs lifted to kgs
logs("The highest recorded lift was " + curr_wght_set_amt.toFixed(0) + "lbs or "+ kgs +"kgs");

}; // end active oninput 


}; // end onload function
```

Answer (score -1):

use window.addEventListener instead:

window.addEventListener('load', yourFunc, false);

You'd have to wrap everything else in a named function (yourFunc)...

Comment: Are you saying this may work if it's not nested inside of the event listener? I will try this, so far it has not worked within... ie.
    window.addEventListener("load") = function() { //here };

Comment: nope try writing it like this: 

window.addEventListener('load', mainFunc, false);

function mainFunc() {
  .. move the oninput, onchange, etc here.
}

Comment: As aforementioned, that's what I did. Still a no go on that. There may be something in another line other than the onload event that is causing the dysfunction. At this point, i'm willing to bet changing to a jQuery version will be the best solution.

Comment: Must be... seems really weird that it's not workin with updated event handling. Mind if I copy the pen and look a bit deeper?